# Redshift ERROR: Overflow for NUMERIC(38,37) when using string columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Im running a query on redshift that aggregates information across multiple temp tables that contain string and timestamp columns. However, when i run the query im running into this error:

ERROR: Overflow for NUMERIC(38,37)

I have tried multiple solutions to fix this:

- Cast as text / varchar
- cast as bigint

but nothing worked for me so far.

I cant seem to explain why i would get this error when dealing with only String and Timestamp columns. How do i fix this?

Sample code:

```
select
 TAB1.accountId 
 ,TAB1.account_type
 ,TAB2.billId
 ,TAB1.type as TAB1_TYPE
 ,TAB1.START_TIME  
 ,TAB1.END_TIME
 ,TAB2.start_time as TAB2_START_TIME  
 ,TAB2.end_time as TAB2_END_TIME
 ,TAB3.producer as TAB3_PRODUCER
 ,TAB3.start_time as TAB3_START_TIME  
 ,TAB3.end_time as TAB3_END_TIME
 ,TAB4.type as TAB4_TYPE
 ,TAB4.start_time as TAB4_START_TIME  
 ,TAB4.end_time as TAB4_END_TIME


from TAB1
LEFT JOIN TAB2 ON TAB1.billId = TAB2.billId
LEFT JOIN TAB3 ON TAB1.billId = TAB3.billId 
LEFT JOIN TAB4 ON TAB1.billId = TAB4.billId 

limit 10
```

Comment: Can you share DDL and sample data?  I suspect one of your temp tables has an unexpected data type

Comment: A quick check you can do is sort desc by len(your_column_name) and see if it's fits the numeric(38,37) precision and scale.